# Cannot select next badge to track

Tags: bug, profile-page, tag-badges, badge-progress

Today, I earned a badge and I wanted to pick the next badge to track myself.

To my surprise, the list is unresponsive when I tap the desired (any) badge option.

[image]

[image]

Comment: As an aside, congrats on earning Illuminator, that's arguably the second-most difficult one to get.

Comment: Illuminator is a very well designed badge. You cannot race around spewing answers, you have to craft helpful answers AND care enough to improve the asked question.  I wish I would have adopted this 2-step procedure to contributing years earlier.